# How to merge multiple point clouds to construct a 3D map?

Tags: c++, kinect, point-cloud-library

I have succeeded in extracting a point cloud using a Kinect, but I cannot go further to save it or to add to it the next captured frame. Here is what I have found so far, and I would love to enhance it so that I can store many point clouds in one file to have a big 3D map.

```
    #include "main.h"
    #include "glut.h"

    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstdio>

    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <Ole2.h>

    #include <Kinect.h>





    // We'll be using buffer objects to store the kinect point cloud
    GLuint vboId;
    GLuint cboId;

    // Intermediate Buffers
    unsigned char rgbimage[colorwidth*colorheight*4];    // Stores RGB color image
    ColorSpacePoint depth2rgb[width*height];             // Maps depth pixels to rgb pixels
    CameraSpacePoint depth2xyz[width*height];            // Maps depth pixels to 3d coordinates

    // Kinect Variables
    IKinectSensor* sensor;             // Kinect sensor
    IMultiSourceFrameReader* reader;   // Kinect data source
    ICoordinateMapper* mapper;         // Converts between depth, color, and 3d coordinates

    bool initKinect() {
        if (FAILED(GetDefaultKinectSensor(&sensor))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (sensor) {
            sensor->get_CoordinateMapper(&mapper);

            sensor->Open();
            sensor->OpenMultiSourceFrameReader(
                FrameSourceTypes::FrameSourceTypes_Depth | FrameSourceTypes::FrameSourceTypes_Color,
                &reader);
            return reader;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void getDepthData(IMultiSourceFrame* frame, GLubyte* dest) {
        IDepthFrame* depthframe;
        IDepthFrameReference* frameref = NULL;
        frame->get_DepthFrameReference(&frameref);
        frameref->AcquireFrame(&depthframe);
        if (frameref) frameref->Release();

        if (!depthframe) return;

        // Get data from frame
        unsigned int sz;
        unsigned short* buf;
        depthframe->AccessUnderlyingBuffer(&sz, &buf);

        // Write vertex coordinates
        mapper->MapDepthFrameToCameraSpace(width*height, buf, width*height, depth2xyz);
        float* fdest = (float*)dest;
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            *fdest++ = depth2xyz[i].X;
            *fdest++ = depth2xyz[i].Y;
            *fdest++ = depth2xyz[i].Z;
        }

        // Fill in depth2rgb map
        mapper->MapDepthFrameToColorSpace(width*height, buf, width*height, depth2rgb);
        if (depthframe) depthframe->Release();
    }

    void getRgbData(IMultiSourceFrame* frame, GLubyte* dest) {
        IColorFrame* colorframe;
        IColorFrameReference* frameref = NULL;
        frame->get_ColorFrameReference(&frameref);
        frameref->AcquireFrame(&colorframe);
        if (frameref) frameref->Release();

        if (!colorframe) return;

        // Get data from frame
        colorframe->CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(colorwidth*colorheight*4, rgbimage, ColorImageFormat_Rgba);

        // Write color array for vertices
        float* fdest = (float*)dest;
        for (int i = 0; i < width*height; i++) {
            ColorSpacePoint p = depth2rgb[i];
            // Check if color pixel coordinates are in bounds
            if (p.X < 0 || p.Y < 0 || p.X > colorwidth || p.Y > colorheight) {
                *fdest++ = 0;
                *fdest++ = 0;
                *fdest++ = 0;
            }
            else {
                int idx = (int)p.X + colorwidth*(int)p.Y;
                *fdest++ = rgbimage[4*idx + 0]/255.;
                *fdest++ = rgbimage[4*idx + 1]/255.;
                *fdest++ = rgbimage[4*idx + 2]/255.;
            }
            // Don't copy alpha channel
        }

        if (colorframe) colorframe->Release();
    }

    void getKinectData() {
        IMultiSourceFrame* frame = NULL;
        if (SUCCEEDED(reader->AcquireLatestFrame(&frame))) {
            GLubyte* ptr;
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
            ptr = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
            if (ptr) {
                getDepthData(frame, ptr);
            }
            glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cboId);
            ptr = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
            if (ptr) {
                getRgbData(frame, ptr);
            }
            glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        }
        if (frame) frame->Release();
    }

    void rotateCamera() {
        static double angle = 0.;
        static double radius = 3.;
        double x = radius*sin(angle);
        double z = radius*(1-cos(angle)) - radius/2;
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(x,0,z,0,0,radius/2,0,1,0);
        angle += 0.002;
    }

    void drawKinectData() {
        getKinectData();
        rotateCamera();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cboId);
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

        glPointSize(1.f);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, width*height);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        if (!init(argc, argv)) return 1;
        if (!initKinect()) return 1;

        // OpenGL setup
        glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
        glClearDepth(1.0f);

        // Set up array buffers
        const int dataSize = width*height * 3 * 4;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSize, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        glGenBuffers(1, &cboId);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSize, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        // Camera setup
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45, width /(GLdouble) height, 0.1, 1000);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        gluLookAt(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0);

        // Main loop
        execute();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're only looking at concatenating point clouds, this could be easily achieved with PCL using the `+=` operator between point clouds. There's a small tutorial about that on the PCL website, that you can find [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/concatenate_clouds.php).

On the other hand, if you're looking for a way to build a big map by merging and stitching different point clouds, you would need to find the set of intersecting features between the point clouds and transform them so that they overlap in the right region. You can do that by building up an algorithm based on the [Iterative Closest Point](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/interactive_icp.php). It might be interesting to look at [KinFu](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_kinfu_large_scale.php#using-kinfu-large-scale), which does that in real-time and produces a mesh from the scanned clouds. The source code is available on the [PCL Project github](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/gpu/kinfu/src/kinfu.cpp).

Comment: Well, += is not a good idea as the result will be quiet messy, mainly if we change the viewpoint from one frame to the other. I think the ICP would be better...

Comment: @Vtik Do you think it is possible to take two frames from different perspectives, but those perspectives are not completely different, because the first perspective and the second may be about 1/2 a meter or 1 meter apart at maximum, and by giving as an input the distance (Odometery) and the angle difference between the first frame and the second I have the two PCLs merged.

Comment: It should work ! I did the same thing for detecting moving vehicules using a lidar mounted on a moving car. So, what we had was, odometry and two successive frames, you then have to registrate both frames (using ICP or odometry) and then you'll have them merged...